# System wide variables for both init scripts and system?

Tags: bash, scripts, systemd, upstart, environment-variables

I created my own init scripts that use variables:

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting Public API"
        sudo -u techops sh ${JBOSS_HOME_PUBLIC_API}/bin/standalone.sh > ${PUBLICAPI_LOGGING_PATH} &
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping Public API"
        sudo -u techops sh ${JBOSS_HOME_PUBLIC_API}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:$((9990 + $PUBLICAPI_PORT_OFFSET)) command=:shutdown > ${PUBLICAPI_LOGGING_PATH} &
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/publicapi {start|stop}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The variables are defined in `/etc/environment` and looks so:

```
PUBLICAPI_PORT_OFFSET=0
PUBLICAPI_LOGGING_PATH=/var/log/publicapi/publicapi.log
JBOSS_HOME_PUBLIC_API=/opt/publicapi
```

...and work after login, when I start and stop the init script manually, but they didn't work for the startup init scripts (which are symbolic links to `/etc/init.d/publicapi` in `/etc/rc2.d/`, `/etc/rc5.d/`, `/etc/rc6.d/`). The startup crashes then, because the variables are unknown.

I was able to fix this by executing `systemctl edit publicapi` which created a file `/etc/systemd/system/publicapi.service.d/local.conf` which looks like this after I edited it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Public API startup script
Documentation=no documentation

[Service]
Environment="JBOSS_HOME_PUBLIC_API=/opt/publicapi"
Environment="PUBLICAPI_PORT_OFFSET=0"
Environment="PUBLICAPI_LOGGING_PATH=/var/log/publicapi/publicapi.log"
```

when I reboot, the startup of the init script works.
But now I have a strange situation:
I always need to define the variable both in `/etc/systemd/system/publicapi.service.d/local.conf` and in `/etc/environment`. If I omit the ones from `/etc/environment`, the init boot scripts are executed but crashes, because the variables seem to be not set (at least after login).
if I comment the variables in `/etc/systemd/system/publicapi.service.d/local.conf` and set them in `/etc/environment` only, the variables are set after login, but the init boot scripts are not executed. What is going on here?
What is the scope of `/etc/systemd/system/publicapi.service.d/local.conf` (since the values are obviously gone after login or maybe not set)? How can I define the variables only once globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the question myself now. After wasting half a day with this tinker crap I've got a solution that work. There are no init scripts anymore in /etc/init.d/ or /etc/rcX.d) or wherever:

*) `/etc/environment`

```
JBOSS_HOME_CONSENT_SERVER=/opt/consent-server
CONSENT_SERVER_LOGGING_PATH=/var/log/consentserver/consent-server.log
CONSENT_SERVER_PORT_OFFSET=3000
```

*) in `/home/techops` create a script `consent-server` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting Consent Server"
        sudo -u techops sh ${JBOSS_HOME_CONSENT_SERVER}/bin/standalone.sh > ${CONSENT_SERVER_LOGGING_PATH} &
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping Consent Server"
        sudo -u techops sh ${JBOSS_HOME_CONSENT_SERVER}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:$((9990 + $CONSENT_SERVER_PORT_OFFSET)) command=:shutdown > ${CONSENT_SERVER_LOGGING_PATH} &
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: systemctl {start|stop} consent-server or pass {start|stop} as parameter"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

*) Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/consent-server.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=consent server startup script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
#if type=oneshot and RemainAfterExit=yes is not set, then the script stops immediately!
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
WorkingDirectory=/home/techops
ExecStart=/home/techops/consent-server start
ExecStop=/home/techops/consent-server stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*) Activate service (will create a symbolic link):

```
systemctl enable consent-server.service
```

After reboot, the service is starting automatically and all the variables are recognized.
You can also start and stop the service with
systemctl start consent-server
systemctl stop consent-server

Comment: Congrats ! You wrote your first systemd service :-)

Answer (score 3):

What's going on here is that you are writing a system V init script on a system that runs systemd.

Your systemd is somewhat backwards compatible and will run these old-style init scripts in a sort of emulation, but treat them as systemd.

I think you'll have a better time abandoning your old init script and writing a new systemd service. This way you don't need `/etc/environment`.

[Here is some further reading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files) on how to write systemd services.

Comment: I need `/etc/environment` because I need it with Wildfly and other scripts as well. At least I already find a solution (see my answer)